# How to send data to specific user using Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I use node.js and socket.io.

I want to send data from the server to the client and displayed to the user with ID = 1

How to send data to specific user?

Comment: A link-only answer has been given below, [which I will preserve here](https://github.com/generalhenry/specificUser).

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used node in awhile so this may not be 100%. Try on server:

```
var id = '<session_id_of_specific_user>',
    io = require('/var/websites/lib/socket.io'),
    user = io.clients[id];
```

Then to send do:

```
var data = {some:'data'};

user.send(data);
```

Hope that's useful. If you tell me more accurately what you need the code to do I could maybe be more helpful.